# fetching object from json string not working in php

Tags: php, json

```
{
    "tripRoute": [{
        "lng": 78.92939102,
        "lat": 22.0533782
    }, {
        "lng": 78.92939102,
        "lat": 22.0533782
    }],
    "bookingId": 195
}
```

this json obj in string format i am sending from android to php server. on php server string is printing correctly. but when i try to get "lng" "bookingId" from String is show null value . this is my php code.

// error on  " ** line "

```
<?php
    include('db_connection.php'); 

    $json= $_REQUEST['tripRoute'];
    $array = json_decode($json,true);

**  $data = $array['tripRoute'][0]['lng'];  // showing Null 


**  $flag['TripPathcode']= $array['bookingId'];   // showing null

    print(json_encode($flag));


?>
```

one more Questiong-  see json string there - "lng": 78.9293102 ,"lat":22.0533 .
there number 78.9293 and 22.0533 not in between " ". i saw other string there integer and double value also in between " ".   does this create some problem ?

Comment: what does `var_dump($json);` give ?

Comment: Strings are enclosed in quotes, numbers are not. PHP is able to use numbers enclosed in quotes; it converts them to numbers when they are used as numbers (added, subtracted etc) and uses them as strings in string context (`echo()` or concatenation, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json_decode()` to convert a JSON String to a native PHP data type.

Your data will be converted to a stdClass object and not an array by default, unless you use the second parameter of `json_decode($string, TRUE);` but there is no need to convert a perfectly good object into an array.

```
<?php
$js = '{

    "tripRoute": [{
        "lng": 78.92939102,
        "lat": 22.0533782
    }, {
        "lng": 78.92939102,
        "lat": 22.0533782
    }],
    "bookingId": 195

}';

$obj = json_decode($js);

print_r($obj);


echo $obj->tripRoute[0]->lng;
echo $obj->bookingId;
```

Answer (score 1):

i got solution ..
my json is printing like this-
{\\ "\\abc":\[{"sdf":.......}]
}

so i use
$json = stripslashes($_REQUEST['tripRoute']);

this solved my problem. thank for your response.